# Difference between ISNULL(SUM(x),0) OR SUM(ISNULL(x,0) in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Which one of the following is correct?

```
        SUM(ISNULL(Sales,0)) AS Sales,
        ISNULL(SUM(Sales),0) AS Sales,
```

Or are they both correct?

Answer (score 22):

They both return the same except if you are running a query on an empty result set.

```
WITH Sales(Sales) AS
(
SELECT 1
)
SELECT
        SUM(ISNULL(Sales,0)) AS Sales,
        ISNULL(SUM(Sales),0) AS Sales
FROM     Sales    
WHERE 1=0
```

Returns

```
Sales       Sales
----------- -----------
NULL        0
```

The `SUM(ISNULL(Sales,0))` version would avoid the ANSI WARNINGS about aggregating `NULL`.

One other subtle difference is that the datatype of the result column of `ISNULL(SUM(Sales),0)` is not regarded as nullable.

Comment: Over use of the word Sales?

WITH Sales_CTE(SalesAndNulls) AS
(
      SELECT 1
      UNION
      SELECT NULL
)
SELECT  
        SUM(ISNULL(SalesAndNulls,0)) AS Sales1,
        ISNULL(SUM(SalesAndNulls),0) AS Sales2
FROM     Sales_CTE   

You get this result with a warning…

Sales1 = 1      Sales2 = 1
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: @Alborz - Yes that's the ANSI WARNING from the `Sales2` version. You could of couse do `ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(SalesAndNulls,0)),0) AS Sales3` if you wanted to return `0` on  an empty result set and not see any warnings.

Answer (score 5):

The first one says

SUM up every Sales field, and if the field is NULL, treat it as zero.

The second says Sum up the sales field, and if the total is NULL, report a zero instead...

However, the SUM() command skips NULL (although you'll be warned about it), so the first one will cause you not to get the error message

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  id INT IDENTITY,
  Alborz INT
)
INSERT  INTO @table
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  NULL

SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Alborz), 0)
FROM    @table
SELECT  SUM(ISNULL(Alborz, 0))
FROM    @table

DELETE  FROM @table

SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Alborz), 0)
FROM    @table
SELECT  SUM(ISNULL(Alborz, 0))
FROM    @table
```

You'll get 21, 21, 0, and NULL.  If you don't want to handle nulls, then ISNULL(SUM(X),0) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference yes. If I am not mistaken

```
5 + NULL = NULL
```

so the first case

```
SUM(ISNULL(Sales,0)) AS Sales
```

would change the null value to 0 and then sum them which would return 5 
while the second case

```
ISNULL(SUM(Sales),0) AS Sales,
```

Would return null in the same data

Answer (score 0):

Second query is correct one.

The first will not return Null only on the empty result set, but also if **ALL VALUES ARE NULL**.

So, to guarantee you won't get Null you have to write:

```
ISNULL(SUM(Sales),0)
```

Observe example:

[image: Example showing that depending on your data IsNull might be required to guarantee that result is Not Null]